# Reading dBase with BDE makes too many file handles

Tags: c#, .net, bde

I want to read dbase files from a remote pc. The problem is this makes very many file handles.

This is a code example that does this. I do it in a thread, because I want to read more files parallel at the same time.

```
using (OleDbConnection oleCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;OLE DB Services=-4;Data Source=\\XXX\d$\dBaseFiles\;Extended Properties=dBase IV;"))
{
    oleCon.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Con open! {0}", oleCon.State);

    OleDbCommand query = new OleDbCommand("select * from rail", oleCon);

    while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'e')
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            using (IDataReader dr = query.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                Console.WriteLine(dr["data"]);

                dr.Close();
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
    oleCon.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("con close! {0}", oleCon.State);                    
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The handles never close when the threads ends. Where is the problem? Has anyone an answer how I can solve this problem!?

Answer (score 0):

First: You are not using BDE but OLE DB (Jet in particular).
Second: You start threads over and over executing the same query in your while loop! Resources are not infinite :) You should set a limit of parallel DataReaders (like 4 at a time f.e.)